# variable not declared in scope using template inheritance

Tags: c++

```
OMStatic.h
template<class Concept> class OMStaticArray :
            public OMAbstructContainer<Concept> {
protected:
    Concept *theLink;
    int count;

    void* AllocateMemory(int size);
    bool  ReleaseMemory(void* pMemory);
    //...
};

OMCollec.h

template<class Concept> class OMCollection :
    public OMStaticArray<Concept>{
public:

void add(Concept p) {
    //...


> if (this->count >= size)

    //...
}
```

In above code, class OMCollection  is inherited from OMStaticArray, my understanding is that we can access protected variables directly, but i am getting an error "count not declared in scope". If i use this->count error is not shown. why i am facing this error, it used to compile in VxWorks 5.5, and now i migrated to Vxworks6.8 i am facing this error if don't use "prefix" before it? what is the reason behnind this ? Please clarify.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there another `count` somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is best explained in the C++ FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.19.

To paraphrase:

> Within `OMCollection<Concept>::add()`, the name `count` does not
>   depend on template parameter `Concept`, so `count` is known as a
>   *nondependent name*. On the other hand, `OMStaticArray<Concept>` is
>   dependent on template parameter `Concept` so `OMStaticArray<Concept>`
>   is called a *dependent name*.
>
> Here's the rule: the compiler does not look in dependent base classes
>   (like `OMStaticArray<Concept>`) when looking up nondependent names
>   (like `count`).

As to why this compiled in an older compiler, the reason is probably that the older compiler wasn't fully compliant with the C++ standard.

Comment: do u kno why the same code with out "this" used to work in VxWorks5.5?

Comment: It's a side-effect of two-phase name lookup. Without this rule, you can't look up any unqualified name in the first phase, since any name that you would find has to be looked up again in the second phase when the base class is known. This would make the first phase rather useless.